# Training On Saturday and Sunday

Tags: recovery, lifting

I've been lifting for a couple of months, Mon-Wed-Fri, no problem.

I changed jobs and now I'm thinking about changing it to Sat-Wed-Sun — I am a lot busier on weekdays now.

I know it will impede my progress.

I know it's not optimal.

But I don't mind too much, becuase I'm expecting it not to matter that much.

Will it be fine? Should I expect progress to be really slow? Or would it be best to lift Sat-Wed and keep Sunday for prehab?

Comment: What makes you think changing days "...will impede my progress'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not optimal, but you'll do just fine for an amateur/hobbyist.**

The reason it's not optimal is you would want a maximum of 48 hours of rest in between working the same muscle group. I'm guessing you're doing bodypart splits? In that case there will be a lot more than 48 hours in between the workouts of the same muscle groups (up to a week probably).

Doing a push and pull split with these trainingdays will probably work best, you should give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

It will be fine. Your body needs time for recovery especially if you're a beginner then it's best to have 24-48 hours gap for the muscles to recover.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be fine.  Try to work out different muscle groups on Saturday and Sunday to allow your muscles to recover.  A [push pull split](http://www.flexonline.com/training/training-style-push-pull) is a great routine for your training frequency